# Connecting Google Cloud Spanner with Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, google-cloud-spanner, database-versioning

I am trying to create containers with Liquibase implementation which can connect with the Google Cloud Spanner.

I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unsupported concurrency mode in query using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

I have searched everywhere but have not got anything substantial to understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Did the answer provided solved your issue?

Comment: No, it did not. liquibase does not support connection to spanner on its own. We have created an out of the box implementation extending liquibase feature.

Comment: @IshanSaxena There is now a community integration for Cloud Spanner with Liquibase here: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/liquibase-spanner

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the [official Google Open Source JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-drivers).

The error you are getting indicates that you are trying to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables while a read/write transaction is active. You should switch to either autocommit mode or to a read-only transaction. You can do so using one of the following SQL statements, or by setting the appropriate mode through code:

1. Switch to autocommit: `SET AUTOCOMMIT=TRUE`
2. Switch to read-only: `SET READ ONLY=TRUE`

It should be sufficient to turn on only one of these two modes, but switching on both should also work.

If that does not work, or if my initial assumption is not correct: Could you share some more information about which JDBC driver you are using and how you are connecting to the database?

**Additional information:** There is now a community based Liquibase integration for Cloud Spanner here: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/liquibase-spanner